# d3 line generator returning null rather than path data string

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path

I'm using d3 v4 to create a line graph. My pathGenerator, using d3's line() method, is returning null instead of a path data string (eg "M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"), and therefore no lines are being drawn.

When I add in console.log()s to try to determine where the issue occurs, the passed in datum appears correctly as an object with percentLoad and efficiency keys with valid numbers as their values. Console.log()s within the .x() and .y() methods do not seem to be invoked, but I'm not sure why this would be.

```
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 100])
    .range([0, chartAreaWidth])

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 2])
    .range([chartAreaHeight, 0])

const pathGenerator = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.percentLoad))
    .y(d => yScale(d.efficiency))
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

const binGroups = chartGroup.selectAll('.binGroups')
    .data(data.bins)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', (d,i) => 'binGroups binGroup' + i)

binGroups.selectAll('.percentLoads')
    .data(d => d)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', (d,i) => 'percentLoads percentLoad' + i)
    .attr('d', d => pathGenerator(d))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[d3.line generator](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line) expects an array of data to generate a line. As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#_line):

> line(data): Generates a line for the given array of data.

In your case, `data.bins` looks like an array so take a look at a sample curve generated using `pathGenerator` function from your code and a few sample bins.

Snippet:

```js
var data = {
 bins: [
   { percentLoad: 30, efficiency: 1.4},
   { percentLoad: 60, efficiency: 0.3},
   { percentLoad: 90, efficiency: 1}    
  ]
}

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([10, 100])
    .range([0, 400])

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 2])
    .range([200, 0])

const pathGenerator = d3.line()
    .x(d => xScale(d.percentLoad))
    .y(d => yScale(d.efficiency))
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

const path = d3.select('svg').append('path').style('fill','none').style('stroke', 'steelblue')
    .attr('d', pathGenerator(data.bins));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="200"></svg>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I got mixed up not having used this particular d3 functionality in a while and didn't remember I needed to pass in the array of objects, rather than the object itself. I just appended the paths to the binsGroups rather than going deeper into the array and it worked! Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help!